# iPhone: Can I split a ViewController's implementation into more than one file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So say I have:

MyViewController.h
MyViewController.m

I'd like to have:
MyViewController.h
MyViewController1.m
MyViewController2.m
(or however many I need)

Kind of like partial classes in .NET, it just makes it easier to organize things...
So is there a way to split an implementation up to more than one file? If so how do I do this? and note that my viewcontroller has a .xib associated with it. Thanks

Comment: One could say that this is a good hint for too big classes.

Comment: I haven't really separated anything to classes, just a bunch of methods inside my viewcontroller(s)... but the implementation is just getting way too long. i wanted to have one implementation for events, and maybe another implementation for everything else like utility methods etc. if you have some other suggestions (instead of splitting) let me know

Comment: The splitting in files is basically the simple way of grouping related things. But the more code and files you create, the harder it is to maintain. And every reference to things in to the other files will become more expensive. I'd try to use this separation as the first hint for new extra classes that handle that specific part (and just that). Small classes and clear responsibilities will pay off. I admit it's easy to forget when writing code. :-)

Comment: especially on an iphone where most programs are smaller.. classes get forgotten sometimes, heh. but thanks point taken ;)

Comment: Just curious, but how long is long? (How many lines)

Comment: See my answer here for an approach -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357775/split-objective-c-code-into-multiple-files/15315895#15315895

Comment: See my answer here for an approach -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357775/split-objective-c-code-into-multiple-files/15315895#15315895

Answer (score 4):

You can use [categories](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) in Objective-C to split your implementation portion of your class. This allows you to logically split your class's methods into separate files.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes you can. As long as you can follow your structure and not get confused, I don't see any issue in it.

Erica Sadun follows the same structure in her [examples](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/blob/master/C05-ViewControllers/01-Two%20Item%20Menu/main.m).

Now, when you get into using XIB's, then you start conflicting.